# Custom Validator not loading on Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4, customvalidator

I built a custom validator but Symfony 4 does not seem to be loading it.

Here is my custom validator:

```
//Status.php
<?php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Status extends Constraint
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

The custom validator

```
//StatusValidator.php
<?php
namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class StatusValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
           // here I straight away adding a violation
            $message = 'Status already exists.';
            $this->context
                ->buildViolation($message)
                ->atPath('status')
                ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

And here is the yaml

```
// config/validator/Status.yaml
App\Entity\Status:
    properties:
        status:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - App\Validator\Constraints\StatusValidator: ~
```

When I submit the form and leave the status blank, the form saves without going through this validation.  In the docs, Symfony 4 should be autowiring these validation.  Cache cleared. same.

Answer (score 0):

In yaml file should be Constraint class App\Validator\Constraints\Status and not Validator class.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html